# data sending server to different client data

Tags: java, rmi

I am doing a project of Restaurant ordering system in that I gave order by using different client and process that order and that order can send different system, e.g:

1. kitchen1
2. Kitechn2, and
3. kitchen3

First I can create different client by using rmi threading concept an and they can send (means all client) data to my server i want to sent that data into different client

How can I do that? I do create different client and send data to the server suggest how can I do that?

Comment: I usually don't comment on details like these, but using punctuation can rapidly increase your chances of being understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMI is a synchronous (request/response) protocol - the client sends a request to the server, which it can respond to.

The server cannot arbitrarily send more data to the client.

The simplest way to asynchronous communication in Java via JMS using a message broker like [Active MQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).

The process would go something like this:

- the server starts and connects to its incoming request queue.
- client 1 creates a temporary queue and registers with the server via the request queue passing the name of its temporary queue.
- the server stores the client and the name of its termporary queue.
- client 2 does the same and server stores the client and the name of its termporary queue.
- client 1 sends a message to the server causing the server to send a message to client 2, which is does via the temporary queue that client 2 registered with the server.
- client 2 reponds to the server causing the server to send a message to client 1, which is does via the temporary queue that client 1 registered with the server.

This can go on until one or both client shuts down, at which point their temporary queue are closed and the server can no longer send messages to that client (though it's best the client de-registers itself).